# How to set inner div width and height to outer div ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div name="outer" style='background-color:red; '>
       <div name="inner"style='background-color:yellow; width:200px'>

       some content 


        </div>
       <div style="clear: both"></div>
      </div>
```

please  take look any one my jsfiddle?

[MY LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/yPMVJ/49/)

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more clearly what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/yPMVJ/50/).. areyou trying to achieve this?

Comment: hi there, i want set inner div content width and height to outer div. like outer div i did not set any width and height to outer div.based on inner div content width and height set to outer div

Comment: thanks lal. really nice

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/yPMVJ/50/)

Add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to your outer div, which will set the width and height of inner div to the outer div.

**UPDATE**

Add this CSS to your outer div. ie to `#LandingDiv`

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
background-color: transparent;
```

Then add

```
background-color: white;
```

to inner div. ie  `#LandingContent`.

Comment: Yes.. any other problems ? @PixelDevendiran

Comment: what is that? @PixelDevendiran

Comment: Yes..I saw the link..what is in that?

Comment: lal above link im using outer div now i set static width and max-height. because inner div width and height not set to outer div width and height. are you understood?

Comment: you have given static height and width to the outer div..is that what you have done? now, could you please tell me, which is the outer div and which one is the inner div..

Comment: what ever inner content width and height set to outer div. i'm really more struggle

Comment: Outer div id : LandingDiv and  inner div id : LandingContent Inner div id binding html code dynamically from database

Comment: im using this css for landing page show on center of the window   .Landing-popup
        {      clear: both;
            float: left;
            background: #fff;
            width: 300px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: auto;
            z-index: 99999;}

Comment: you got it. lal one thing remember i want show landing page center of window and also its responsive website.now tell me solution friend.how solve. this problem

Comment: Now this is centered..what is the issue if you do it like this?

Comment: issues is inner div content width and height and not set to outer div see inner height very small but outer div height very length

Comment: that is because you have `bottom:0` in your css for outer div.

Comment: yes i know i want change means div not center of window

Comment: otherwise you have any idea how to center div based on div content (dynamic)

Comment: lal thanks. its chrome and firebox but not working IE10 like not display anything

Comment: flex not support IE lal

Comment: ok lal when you finished please posted here once again thanks lot friend

Comment: now uploaded to server for static position.please when you finished post here